# Connect to a remote Windows Sybase database from Ubuntu via PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, sybase, sqlanywhere

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise

I'm trying to use PHP to connect to a remote Windows Sybase database. Let us assume Windows 7 Enterprise SP1. I'm currently doing this in PHP:

```
$db = sybase_connect("10.1.208.111", "$user", "$pass");
```

And I'm getting an error of:

> Warning: sybase_connect(): Unable to connect to server: 10.1.208.111

I understand that the server I'm connecting to (10.1.208.111), needs to be in the interfaces file. I'm trying to figure out where that is, or even if I have one on the Ubuntu server (I'm still new to linux itself). I read that the path for the file is located in the SYBASE environmental variable. I don't know where that is either. Can anyone shed some light? I can offer more information if you need it, I just don't know what you need right off the bat.

PS: The windows machine has Micros RES installed on it. That's the database I'm trying to pull data from. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database..which Sybase product are you trying to connect to?

Comment: SQL Anywhere 11 I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default installation directory for Sybase ASE in windows is `C:\sybase`, so your interfaces (`interfaces.ini`) should be located there.

For SQL Anywhere, the interfaces file is called `SQL.ini`, and it's location varies, but you should be able to do a search of your system drive to find it.

For SQL Anywhere you probably want to use the PHP apis that are provide by SAP Sybase.  The SQL Anywhere documentation is a pretty good place to start, as it covers all the pieces that need to be installed to get SQL Anywhere to talk to PHP.

[SQL Anywhere 11: SQL Anwhere PHP API](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbprogramming_en11/php-about.html)

You may also be able to find good information over at the [SAP Community Network site for SQL Anywhere](https://scn.sap.com/community/sql-anywhere).

Comment: I don't have any sybase folders.  I have C:\Program Files (x86)\SQL Anywhere 11

Comment: @bwalleshauser That's why it's important to note more details in your questions.  My answre is based on Sybase ASE, not Sybase SQLAnywhere.  I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the difference between the two.  This whitepage for SQL Anywhere is saying I have to allow the PHP extension to use the libraries located in the SQL Anywhere installation...but the SQL Anywhere installation is on the remote server, and the whitepaper has all relative paths.  Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: There are both client and server files included in the installation.  You may have to download a copy (or some of the lib files mentioned in the links) and load them locally.